# Configuring TLS Trust in Mobile First for Push Notifications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have `MFP V8` installed and running and from the administration console.

The push service is showing as up.

The OAuth URI for the push configuration is set to a `HTTP server cluster` using an `internal CA`.

Once application installed, there is an option to configure push notifications under the application which once clicked-on, gives me an error in the console about **JSON parsing**.

Logs tell that

> the call to the OAuth URI is generating a 500 internal server error
>   due to an SSL trust failure for the internal CA

Wheras the internal CA is in the trust store for all application servers and the HTTP server is returning the right certificate with the full chain.

I've been doing a bit of reading and I can see that the applications may have their own trust stores.

Does `MFP` override the website WebSphere default handling of SSL trust and do I need to do any special configuration for mobile first or the application?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try adding the HTTP server certificate chain to the MFP keystore as well and try?

Comment: Thanks Vivin, for the suggestion I don't/didn't have a dedicated MFP key store.  It appears that MFP does override the default WAS key stores, I'm not sure of the reasoning behind this as WAS has advanced features in this area.  If you don't have a MFP key store configured then trust is based on the default cacerts file in the JVM, not the WAS trust stores.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting this issue:
Yes, MFP overrides the default WAS TLS/Trust store settings.  If you don't have a key store configured in MFP then the default cacerts file of the JVM is used by default.